# XPath to get attribute names in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath

I have an XML file, for example:

```
<a b="123" c="456"/>
```

and I want to get all attribute names and values using xpath from Oracle SQL. Executing

```
select extractvalue(value(p), 'text()')
  from xmltable('/*/@*' passing xmltype('<a b="123" c="456"/>')) p;
```

I get only `["123","456"]`, but I want to get `["b", "c"]` too. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `/*/@*` to `/*/@*/local-name()`